# If any first-in-line English letter is lowercase, uppercase it

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression, posix, tr

I have a markdown document `myfile.md` with a list of English sentences in which some the first letters are lowercased and some are uppercased.
All English sentences start with standard English letters; no special characters are used:

> x
>   X
>   x

I need a function by that logic:
*If any first-in-line English letter is lowercase, uppercase it*

So to change the file to be looked like this:

> X
>   X
>   X

### What I have tried

#### 1) `tr`

I thought to try to do so with `tr` with regex, based on `'tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' myfile.md`  but neither I found a way to combine regex in `tr`, nor I found a way to process data inside a file with `tr`.
Rather, I only found a way to transform text in shell prompt as with:

```
echo x | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
```

> X

#### 2) `sed`

```
sed 's/^[a-z]*/[A-Z]/' myfile.md
sed -r 's/^[a-z]*/[A-Z]/' myfile.md
```

But after executing either, `myfile.md` still contains

> x
>   X
>   x

instead:

> X
>   X
>   X

### My question

How could I use the described logic from shell, without using any CLUI text editors such as `nano` or `vim`?

Comment: (1) What does “first-in-line English letter” mean?  The first character in the line (if it’s a letter)?  The first *non-blank* character in the line (if it’s a letter)?  (I.e., what if the text is indented with spaces and/or tabs?)  The first letter in the line?  How should lines that begin `++n` or ``17 quick`` be handled? (2) The letters `C`, `K`, `O`, `P`, `S`, `U`, `V`, `W`, `X` and `Z` are (essentially) identical in upper-case and lower-case (differing only in size), and `I`, `J` and `Y` are very similar (at least in some fonts).  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … Your example would be clearer if you used letters that are obviously different in upper- and lower-case versions.  Or at least use words.  ``COWS`` and ``ZOO`` may look a lot like `cows` and `zoo`, but `Cows` and `Zoo` are clearly different.  `SOCK` / `sock` / `Sock` and `POP` / `pop` / `Pop` are even better.  (Ideally, use a word whose letters are distinguishable, like `MERGED` / `merged` / `Merged` or `REGARD` / `regard` / `Regard`.)

Comment: Hello ; for me, a letter is a letter so I can't understand "if it's a latter"; I am not sure what you meant by non-blank character. I didn't say indentation makes a difference - for me it doesn't, in this case.

Comment: I think the amount of similarity between lowercase to uppercase shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `\U` function in GNU sed.

```
 s/^\([a-z]\)/\U\1/
```

so this captures a single character at the start of the line if it is lowercase, and upper cases it.

As the \U leaves other things alone, this can be simplified to

```
s/\(.\)/\U\1/
```

as the `.` will match the first character (if any) on the line.

Comment: Or just `s/^[a-z]/\U&/`. Note that unless you're in the C locale, `[a-z]` is likely to include more letters (and even non-letters, and sequences of characters) than the _English_ ones. Things like `æ`, `ß`, `℉`, ``...

Comment: I assume the POSIX `[:lower:]` character class is the same.

Comment: I ran `sed 's/^\([a-z]\)/\U\1/' languages.md` and `sed 's/\(.\)/\U\1/' languages.md` (and I also tried double quotes instead single quotes but no change was made).

Comment: The command as written will output the new text to the terminal. You either need `-i` to do an inplace edit or redirect the output to a **new** filename, See the answer from Thor if you don't have Gnu sed. Do use single quotes rather than double quotes.

Comment: Oh yes, I am sorry, about 2 years I didn't use `sed`, I totally didn't recall about `-i`. Now it worked - thank you,

Comment: Even shorter: `s/./\U&/`. The dot will match the first character of the line, and the `\U` will upper that character which will be replaced by the `s///` command. This will fail only if there are non-characters at the start of the line.

Answer (score 5):

`tr` will not help you here as upper-casing with `tr` would turn *all* characters into upper-case (`tr` only has a character-at-a-time context, so it won't ever know about "start of line" or "beginning of a word").

`sed` could do it if you used GNU `sed`.  However, the way you show will replace the first upper-case character(s) by the literal text `[A-Z]`.

---

Since this question is tagged with [posix](/questions/tagged/posix), here's a standard-compliant `awk` solution that will simply uppercase the first character on any line:

```
awk '{ ch = toupper(substr($0,1,1)); sub(".", ""); $0 = ch $0; print }' file
```

What the `awk` command is doing is extracting the first character on the line using `substr()`.  It then uppercases it and assigns it to the variable `ch`.  The first character on the line is then removed using `sub()` and the upper cased `ch` is prepended to the line.  Then the line is printed.

Testing this:

```
$ cat file
Apple
orange
grapefruit
Mango
```

```
$ awk '{ ch = toupper(substr($0,1,1)); sub(".", ""); $0 = ch $0; print }' file
Apple
Orange
Grapefruit
Mango
```

If there is some indentation of the data (i.e., there are blanks at the start of the line), then instead use

```
awk '{ ch = toupper(substr($1,1,1)); sub(".", "", $1); $1 = ch $1; print }' file
```

(this would however remove the indentation).

---

If you're happy using Perl to do this, the following would upper-case the first character on each line, in a similar way to how the first `awk` program above does it.

```
perl -pe 'substr($_,0,1,uc(substr($_,0,1)))' file
```

although using

```
perl -pe 's/^./\U$&/' file
```

would be shorter and more "Perl-like".

Replace `^.` in that expression with `[^[:blank:]]` to replace the first non-blank character on the line (this would *preserve* any indentation).

Comment: A `sub(".", ch)` is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capitalize the first non-blank character in the line
(if it’s a letter), use this variation on [Kusalananda’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/556900/80216#556925):

```
awk '{ ch = substr($1,1,1); uch = toupper(ch); if (ch != uch) sub(ch, uch); print }'
```

Note that this does not clobber spaces.

---

If you want to capitalize the first letter in the line,
use this variation on [icarus’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/556900/80216#556901):

```
sed 's/\([a-z]\)/\U\1/'
```

i.e., leave out the `^`.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX sed:

```
h
s/(.).*/\1/
y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/
G
s/(.)\n.?(.*)/\1\2/
```

Comment: Are you sure this works as posted in POSIX sed?  [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) says “The *sed* utility shall support the BREs described in XBD *[Basic Regular Expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03),* with the following additions …”, and I don’t see anything in there about plain parentheses being accepted for grouping, or non-greedy patterns working.  To get it to work in GNU sed, I needed to change `(`…`)` to `\(`…`\)` and change `.?` to **`.`**. Or add ``-r``.